# How do i write unit test case for the subscribe inside ngOnInit?

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing

Here i am subscribing to the data in the separate file (service)

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getSelectedEvent.subscribe(
        trendsPageEventListener => {
            this.zone.run(()=>{
                this.trendsPageEventListener = trendsPageEventListener; 
               });
        });       
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for JASMINE framework. Similarly could be used for Jest also.

Context: create a stub for the method in a service and return a stub value.When you run ngOnInit, the observable will be replace with your stub value and subscribe by your component.

In your mock service(its better to inject mock services instead of real services in test config), `getSelectedEvent =  jasmine.createSpy('getSelectedEvent');`

In your unit test, `... mockService.getSelectedEvent.and.returnValue(of("any value"))...`
then run fixture.detectChanges(), it will automatically call your functions inside ngOnInit.

Comment: can you please elaborate @KiraAG?

Comment: Can you post a stackblitz of what you have tried? I might be able to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Unit test solution:

`example.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { ExampleService } from './example.service';

@Component({})
export class ExampleComponent {
  trendsPageEventListener: any;
  constructor(private service: ExampleService, private zone: NgZone) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getSelectedEvent().subscribe((trendsPageEventListener) => {
      this.zone.run(() => {
        this.trendsPageEventListener = trendsPageEventListener;
      });
    });
  }
}
```

`example.service.ts`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class ExampleService {
  getSelectedEvent(): Observable<string> {
    return of('real trends page event listener');
  }
}
```

`example.component.spec.ts`:

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { ExampleComponent } from './example.component';
import { ExampleService } from './example.service';

fdescribe('55234033', () => {
  let exampleServiceSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<ExampleService>;
  let component: ExampleComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ExampleComponent>;
  beforeEach(() => {
    exampleServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('ExampleService', [
      'getSelectedEvent',
    ]);
    exampleServiceSpy.getSelectedEvent.and.returnValue(
      of('fake trend page event listener')
    );

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ExampleComponent],
      providers: [{ provide: ExampleService, useValue: exampleServiceSpy }],
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ExampleComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });
  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeDefined();
  });
  it('should pass', () => {
    expect(component.trendsPageEventListener).toBeUndefined();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.trendsPageEventListener).toBe(
      'fake trend page event listener'
    );
    expect(exampleServiceSpy.getSelectedEvent).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

test result:

[image]